# Production mode doesnt load any content for custom module

Tags: magento2, module, layout, custom, controllers

I have created a custom module in Magento 2. In developer mode it is working well, however same module does not show any content in the production mode of Magento its show only white screen. There is no error in logs, apache, system, debug logs are empty. Any suggestions?

I tried everything 
Cache
Reindexing
Permission

Comment: bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: already tried that too

Comment: we can't help you with the information you provided. are you talking about different installations?

Comment: same application, module is working for development server but not for production server

Comment: does it work on your local machine in production mode?

Comment: no its working on local server, I tried to enable production mode :(

Comment: Your magento version please

Comment: 2.2.8 magento version

Comment: After enabling the production have you checked the template files for module generated properly in var/view_preprocessed. Also try disabling  Js minify, merge and have a check in production mode

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, checked the code in generated folder too

Comment: Delete the generated/metadata/global.php

Comment: @Nickool I tried that too :( but doesnt help